# Partial derivative of weighted matrix factorization?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, matrix-calculus, machine-learning, matrix-decomposition

$C \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, X \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, W \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times k}, H \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$

$W_{i.}$ is the $i$th row of $W$

$H_{j.}$ is the $j$th row of $H$

$$f=arg\min_{W, H} \sum_{i,j} C_{ij} \circ (X_{ij} - W_{i.}H_{j.}^T)^2$$

$\circ$: hadamard product (element-wise product)

$$\frac {\partial{f}} {\partial{W}} = ?$$
$$\frac {\partial f}{\partial H} = ?$$

Hi everyone,

I am chemoinformatic background (poor for mathmatics). Recently, I was learning matrix factorization. That is given a matrix **X** with {0, 1} entries, which was decomposed to two matrices **W** and **H**. And in order to obtain the optimal **W** and **H**, one need solve the partial derivative of **W** and **H** to objective function *f*. I can proof the partial derivative for W and H if the matrix factorization (MF) is not weighted according to the relationship between Frobenius norm and trace. However, for the weighted MF (like the figure, it has another weighting matrix **C**, and **C** hadamard product the original one), I can not get the partial derivative for W and H even though some papers (such as: "collaborative filtering for implicit feedback datasets"; "Evaluation of one-class collaborative filtering") have proven them.

Can you give me a trick how to deal with hadamard product(element-wised product)? can it change to normal matrix product? How to get partial derivative for W and H? can linear algebra or matrix algebra solve them?

Denote: **X** is a matrix with {0, 1} entries and **X** was decomposed to **W** and **H** matrices. **C** is the weighting matrix which has the same dimension with **X**.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to latex your drawing and I don't understand what you mean to say at the top. What is the difference between the two matrices denoted W that you have specified? They clearly have different dimensions, so is one some kind of restriction of the other? What does the arrow mean?

Comment: Also, I assume you're talking about matrices over $\mathbb{R}$. Right?

Comment: sorry for confusing. I re-edit them and use differ characters to denote them. In fact, it is matrix factorization problem. I would like to decompose X into W and H, to make sure: X = WH^T. In order to get the optimal W and H, I will perform partial derivative to W and H respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For convenience let 
$$\eqalign{
 M &= X - WH^T \cr
dM &= -(dW\,H^T + W\,dH^T) \cr
}$$

Then write the objective function in terms of the [Frobenius (:) inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product) and [Hadamard ($\circ$) product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Hadamard_product), and find its differential
$$\eqalign{
 f &= C:M\circ M \cr
df &= 2\,C:M\circ dM \cr
   &= 2\,C\circ M : dM \cr
   &= -2\,C\circ M : (dW\,H^T + W\,dH^T) \cr
}$$
Now set $dH=0$ to obtain the gradient wrt $W$
$$\eqalign{
df &= -2\,C\circ M : dW\,H^T \cr
   &= -2\,(C\circ M)\,H : dW \cr\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial W} &= -2\,(C\circ M)\,H \cr
}$$
Similarly, setting $dW=0$ yields the gradient wrt $H$
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial H} &= -2\,(C\circ M)^T\,W \cr\cr
}$$
The above derivation uses the fact that the Frobenius and Hadamard products commutate with themselves and with each other, i.e. 
$$\eqalign{
A\circ B &= B\circ A \cr
A:B &= B: A \cr
A\circ B:C &= A:B\circ C \cr
}$$
and on a rearrangement property of the Frobenius product, which follows from the cyclic property of the trace
$$\eqalign{
AB:C &= A:CB^T \cr
AB:C &= B:A^TC \cr
}$$
and on the differential properties of the products
$$\eqalign{
d(A:B) &= A:dB + B:dA \cr
d(A\circ B) &= A\circ dB + B\circ dA \cr
}$$

Comment: Thanks hans. Can you provide me a book you learned about matrix (linear) algebra and some book about (hadamard) matrix calculus? Currently, I am trying to proof you provide the fact and formula. It is very nice to know 'the Frobenius and Hadamard products are commutative with each other'. It is difficult to find such formula in the internet I tried though I proof it. Algebra is very powerful.

Comment: For the gradient wrt H: is it should be -2(C o M)^T W,  not the W^T? Right? Thanks.

Comment: No, you must account for the transpose in the $dH^T\,$ term.

Comment: yes, I consider it.  dH^T = (dH)^T. I do not know how to upload my proof. Can you write down your proof. I tried many times and get 'W' not 'W^T'. thanks.

Comment: Here is my proof. can download the proof and correct me:   https://www.dropbox.com/s/auygqvvyk3idfth/proof_Untitled.png?dl=0

Comment: Sorry borther you again. I still can not get your result about the gradient for H: This is my result. Pleas Help to correct me. What is wrong for my answer:   https://www.dropbox.com/s/auygqvvyk3idfth/proof_Untitled.png?dl=0

Comment: Your proof is correct.  Well done.  I will correct the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Your method is so good. Especially using the Frobenius product method. It seems universal to proof derivative of trace.